# understanding cypher output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like this:
(2)<-[0:CHILD]-(1)-[1:CHILD]->(3)
In words: Node 1,2 and 3 (all with names); Edges 0 and 1

I write the following cypher-query:

```
START nodes = node(1,2,3), relationship = relationship(0,1) 
RETURN nodes, relationship
```

and got as a result:

```
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
==> | nodes                          | relationship |
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[1]{name->"Risikogruppe2"} | :CHILD[0] {} |
==> | Node[1]{name->"Risikogruppe2"} | :CHILD[1] {} |
==> | Node[2]{name->"Beruf 1"}       | :CHILD[0] {} |
==> | Node[2]{name->"Beruf 1"}       | :CHILD[1] {} |
==> | Node[3]{name->"Beruf 2"}       | :CHILD[0] {} |
==> | Node[3]{name->"Beruf 2"}       | :CHILD[1] {} |
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
==> 6 rows, 0 ms
```

now my question:
why I became all nodes twice and relationships three time? I just want to get all of it one time.

thanks for your time ^^

Comment: Both starting sets form a cross product of input values for the queries.

Answer (score 1):

The way Cypher works is very similar to SQL. When you create your variables in your START clause, you're sort of doing a `from nodes, relationships` in SQL (tables). The reason you're getting a cartesian product of all of the possible values for the two, is because you're not doing any sort of `match` or `where` to filter them, so it's basically like:

```
select *
from nodes, relationships
```

Where you forgot to put the foreign key relationship between the tables.

In Cypher, you do this by doing a match, usually:

```
start n=node(1,2,3), r=relationship(0,1)
match n-[r]-m // find where the n nodes and the r relationships point (to m)
return *
```

But since you have no match, you get a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

You should only see the nodes and relationships once, unless you do some matching.

Tried to reproduce your problem, but I haven't been able to.

http://tinyurl.com/cobd8oq

Is it possible for you to create an console.neo4j.org example of your problem?

Thanks,

Andrés

Comment: oh my fault, i give you the false query. http://tinyurl.com/bpunlnh shows the right query. but my question is still there. why are both relationships in node 2 and 3, just one of these connected to this. ok i do not matching, but why the table shows in the right row not just 2 relationships?

Comment: What's the use case? It looks like without the match, you're just getting sort of a cross product of nodes and relationships without much meaning

Comment: START nodes = node(1,2,3) match (nodes)-[r:CHILD]-(x) return nodes,r will give you all the nodes and the relations they have

Comment: its just a simple example, without meaning. I want to start on these points and return them. i just wondering abaout the redundant output